# Who's piloting the Ghost in The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

During the climax of the Battle of Exegol, with Lando's reinforcements, we can clearly see the *VCX-100 light freighter "Ghost"* jumping in the fray just behind the Falcon.
[image: VCX-100 light freighter "Ghost"]

During the following battle we have some others fragments which shows again the ship darting around.

While I'm assuming it is Jacen Syndulla piloting it, I can't find any source for this statement.

**Is there any canon reference to the pilot of the Ghost during *The Rise of Skywalker*?**

Comment: [Star Wars 9: Who’s Piloting The Ghost In Rise of Skywalker?](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-9-rise-skywalker-ghost-rebels-ship/) - In short, we don't know and no-one's telling

Comment: Needs a free-hand red circle for those of us unfamiliar with "the Ghost".

Comment: @Skooba added a second image!

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a ship of the same class as the Ghost?

Comment: Given Hera is not that much old than Luke and Leia (she was a young girl during the Clone Wars), there's no reason it couldn't be Hera too,

Comment: @psubsee2003 yep Hera should be 60-something during the events of TRoS, so it could be her too!

Answer (score 1):

**We Don't Know**

Neither the film nor its novelization or graphic novel adaptation say anything about the ship's crew.

To speculate, Hera and/or Jacen Syndulla are the likeliest options. Hera continued to serve the New Republic past the original series, as seen in works such as *Alphabet Squadron* and *Squadrons*, making it possible that she was still fighting in *Rise of Skywalker*. While she would be about 64, similarly "experienced" veterans such as Lando (78) and Wedge (played by an actor who was about 70) were known to have participated.